# Character Reversal without reversing numbers

Tags: java, python, c++, string, reverse

I need a code to reverse order only the alphabets, without reversing the numbers.
For Ex. Suppose I have :
3 D F 4 B 5 H 6 K (in a string or array) I should produce output:
3 K H 4 B 5 F 6 D

Comment: Can you show your approach?

Comment: You can scan the input once, storing the occurrences of each number/character and their index in two separate arrays. Then create a third array to reverse the positions of alphabets, keeping the positions of numbers same. Or you can just use two indexes(one from starting and one from end) to do this in a single go.

Comment: **You Should first code and if you're unable to resolve then ask Questions in SOF** Yet go through this https://github.com/NsrM/hello-world/blob/master/StackOflow1 for java code for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def reverse_besides_number(l):
  # convert number in list to a dict
  # record the index
  d = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(l) if v.isdigit()}
  # record the character in list
  c = [i for i in l if not i.isdigit()]
  c.reverse()
  # insert
  for key, value in d.items():
      c.insert(key, value)
  return c
```